# Can I import solidity code (or ABIs) into vyper?

Tags: solidity, abi, import, vyper

Let's say I have a contract in `solidity`:

```js
pragma solidity 0.8.8;

contract MyContract{
    function getFive() public pure returns (uint256){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Could I import, inhert, etc in `vyper`? Or do something with it's ABI to import into vyper?

Ie in vyper:

```py
from MyContract import getFive
```

Additional:

- Would the best thing to do be to rewrite contracts into vyper interfaces if I just wanted to interact with a contract?
- Is there some way to grab the solidity bytecode of a function and drop it into vyper? (Or even the vyper bytecode...)

Comment: "Would the best thing to do be to rewrite contracts into vyper interfaces if I just wanted to interact with a contract?"

yes, this is the preferred method

Comment: "Is there some way to grab the solidity bytecode of a function and drop it into vyper? (Or even the vyper bytecode...)"

no, as the vyper compiler cannot provide safety guarantees this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vyper supports importing interfaces from JSON ABI files. You can convert a vyper contract to a JSON ABI interface file with `vyper -f abi foo.vy`, and you can convert a solidity contract to a JSON ABI interface file with `solc --abi foo.sol`. In the latest version of vyper, v0.3.3, you would import `foo.json` using the following syntax:

```
import foo as Foo

my_foo: Foo  # an external contract which has the interface defined by foo.json
```